# How can I make sure sentry is capturing my exception?

Tags: laravel, sentry

I have implemented sentry in a new laravel project. Sending a test exception seems to work fine:

```
root@d816d48eed86:/app# php artisan sentry:test
[sentry] Client DSN discovered!
[sentry] Generating test event
[sentry] Sending test event
[sentry] Event sent with ID: d88ff2add86342989da27a8c75ec0562
```

I can also see that it's received by sentries webserver:

```
sentry_1     | 10.10.65.1 - - [12/Nov/2019:09:05:12 +0000] "POST /api/35/store/ HTTP/1.0" 200 366 "-" "sentry.php.laravel/1.4.1"
```

However, the exception never shows up in sentry.

I am using the `sentry/sentry-laravel` v1.4.1 package.

How can I debug this?

Comment: Do you mean: the exception the test artisan command throws, does not show in theSentry dashboard?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: I think I've run into the same problem now. Are you hosting sentry in docker? I have a hunch that there's something about sentry's DSN parser that doesn't accept docker's `sentry_1` as a valid hostname. when I set up a proxy with a full hostname e.g. `sentry.example.com` then it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, it's not enough to start a sentry container. You also have to spin up containers running a cron and worker container:

```
  sentry:
    image: sentry:9
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      <<: *sentry-config
    links:
      - postgres
      - memcached
      - redis
    ports:
      - "9000"
  cron:
    image: sentry:9
    links:
     - redis
     - postgres
    command: "sentry run cron"
    environment:
      <<: *sentry-config
  worker:
    image: sentry
    links:
     - redis
     - postgres
    command: "sentry run worker"
    environment:
      <<: *sentry-config
    postgres:
    image: postgres:11
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=sentry
      - POSTGRES_DB=sentry
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=sentry
  redis:
    image: redis:5-alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
  memcached:
    image: memcached:1.5-alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
```